# Silverstripe 3 Extending Error Mail with HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Tags: silverstripe

By default the error mail only takes these server variables from log.php:

```
protected static $log_globals = array(
    '_SERVER' => array(
        'HTTP_ACCEPT',
        'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET', 
        'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING', 
        'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE', 
        'HTTP_REFERRER',
        'HTTP_USER_AGENT',
        'HTTPS',
        'REMOTE_ADDR',
    ),
);
```

How do I add 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' to my error e-mails without modifying the core files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually possible via the new configuration system in Silverstripe. Have a YAML config file with the following:

```
SS_Log:
  log_globals:
    '_SERVER': 
      - 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'
```

This adds `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` to the `_SERVER` array on the `log_globals` static variable.